# What addons should I use to disable css and hide image for a specific website on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I use Google Chrome on Windows 7. There are 2 - 3 websites I like to visit but their css are bad, they use very bright color which is not good for my eyes.

I tried to search for an addon that can do this but I could not find one. Keywords that I have tried are "chrome disable css", "chrome black and white", "chrome text only". The only addon I found and it works almost everything I want is PlainClothes but it does not disable css on buttons, and other control.

Are there any addon to do this in Chrome?

Comment: Just compose your own user-script.

Comment: @Zoredache I don't know how you compose a user-script. Do you have a link that teach how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Adblock Plus for Chrome can hide specific image on a specific website. You need to click on Adblock Plus icon and choose 'Block element'. It also can block css but on all websites, if you add *.css rule in Filters options (custom filters tab). The method affect only on external stylesheets.